no websocket network activity when debugging a Blazor serverside app locally
I'm working on a Blazor app (.net 8, server side, Visual Studio 2022) and I'm not seeing any WebSocket network activity at all when debugging and running locally in Chrome.  The app works ok, it fetches and updates data in a local SQL server instance but there is nothing at all showing in the WebSocket activity screen in the chrome debugger.  Are there any other steps I need to take to see the activity ?

It looks work on my side:

I am using the default blazor app, and I am using the default visual studio settings, no setting sync.
How to reset the visual studio settings:
Reset the language environment collection settings:




And to make sure not effected by the settings of the async user's settings, please turn off the user settings async:
7


That didn't work for me, still no messages

If I select "All" I do initially get css & javascript activity but no websocket activity at all, even after retrieving data from a database and displaying onscreen

Ive even tried disabling my anti virus software (Norton) but it makes no difference, I cant get any websocket activity

@misuk What is the chrome version on your side?
